# Iterate over SQLite results from R

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm new using R as language programming. And now I'm triying a basic loop over the results of a query, but I can't do it properly, let's see:

I have a DB named RDB.sqlite with a table named PERDIDAS, with the following structure

---

### | ID | PERIODO | VALOR |

I have the following R code:

```
library("RSQLite")

con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "bd/RDB.sqlite")

periodo <- function(num){


    results<-dbGetQuery(con, paste("SELECT PERIODO,VALOR FROM PERDIDAS WHERE PERIODO = ",num,""))


    # WHEN I TRY ITERATE OVER THE RESULTS...

    for (result in results){
      print(result)
    }

}
results(2)
```

When I run this script, that simply calls the results function passing it 2 as parameter. That's what I see on console:

[1] 2 2 2 2

[1] 2219.398 2218.256 2209.780 2236.723

What is wrong ? I don't know how properly iterate over all elements.. could you help me? I expect to see something like that on console:

[1] 2219.398

[2] 2218.256

[3] 2209.780

[4] 2236.723

Comment: Just after `results<-fetch(results,-1) // fetch all results`, put `print(class(results))`. What do you get?

Comment: I shouldn't write these line, with it, the script throws an error, without it, runs ok, but I still having the same issue

Comment: @luigonsec that makes no sense

Comment: It should not throw an error. Perhaps post the code with the line added?

Comment: I just had `results<-fetch(results , -1)` just after `results<-dbGetQuery()...`, but has the same effect that the code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned result of using `dbGetQuery()` is a data frame, not a list as your `for` loop assumes.

Hence, simply view the results like any other data frame after the query command:

```
View(results) # pop-up window of data frame

print(results)  # console output of data frame

for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
  print(results[i,])  # iterate through each row of data frame
}

for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
  print(results$column[[i]]) # iterate through each row of selected column in df
}
```

Comment: And how could I iterate over the results, or how could I get the returned element in a iterable object ?

Comment: I edited to include `for` loops through data frame's rows. But curious, why do you want to iterate over results as `print()` outputs all rows in one command?